# Finding dates in date range is not working - PHP Date

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have dates in datetime format in the database this way:

```
53  13  2344    4   Alaska  0   2015-02-03 08:15:37
54  12  567 25  Alabama 0   2015-02-04 08:16:23
55  36  899 1   Arizona 0   2015-02-05 08:17:15
56  35  325 1   West Virginia   0   2015-02-05 08:18:19
57  13  874 2   Alaska  0   2015-02-05 08:21:26
58  37  6563    1   Indiana 0   2015-02-07 08:22:05
59  36  644 2   Tennessee   0   2015-02-07 08:23:54
60  35  435 1   District of Columbia    0   2015-02-05 08:26:10
61  34  324 2   Idaho   0   2015-02-07 08:36:56
62  13  1235    5   Alaska  0   2015-02-07 13:35:23
```

Now, I want to pull records for `2015-02-05 AND 2015-02-07`

The SQL Query I am using is:

```
SELECT * FROM `web_matter_attorney` WHERE `ma_datetime` BETWEEN '2015-02-05' AND  '2015-02-07'
```

But it only returns records for 5th date skipping records for 7th. Means it is not pulling records for 7th as well.

I have also tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `web_matter_attorney` WHERE `ma_datetime` >= '2015-02-05' AND `ma_datetime` <= '2015-02-07'
```

But still no luck and same response.

My database field for date name is `datetime`

My table structure with data is:

```
CREATE TABLE `web_matter_attorney` (
  `wma_ID` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `att_ID` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `ma_number` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `ma_case_ID` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `ma_state` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `ma_override` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `ma_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`wma_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=63 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of web_matter_attorney
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `web_matter_attorney` VALUES ('52', '32', '5494984984', '17', 'Virginia', '0', '2015-01-20 14:48:55');
INSERT INTO `web_matter_attorney` VALUES ('53', '13', '2344', '4', 'Alaska', '0', '2015-02-03 08:15:37');
INSERT INTO `web_matter_attorney` VALUES ('54', '12', '567', '25', 'Alabama', '0', '2015-02-04 08:16:23');
INSERT INTO `web_matter_attorney` VALUES ('55', '36', '899', '1', 'Arizona', '0', '2015-02-05 08:17:15');
INSERT INTO `web_matter_attorney` VALUES ('56', '35', '325', '1', 'West Virginia', '0', '2015-02-05 08:18:19');
INSERT INTO `web_matter_attorney` VALUES ('57', '13', '874', '2', 'Alaska', '0', '2015-02-05 08:21:26');
INSERT INTO `web_matter_attorney` VALUES ('58', '37', '6563', '1', 'Indiana', '0', '2015-02-07 08:22:05');
INSERT INTO `web_matter_attorney` VALUES ('59', '36', '644', '2', 'Tennessee', '0', '2015-02-07 08:23:54');
INSERT INTO `web_matter_attorney` VALUES ('60', '35', '435', '1', 'District of Columbia', '0', '2015-02-05 08:26:10');
INSERT INTO `web_matter_attorney` VALUES ('61', '34', '324', '2', 'Idaho', '0', '2015-02-07 08:36:56');
INSERT INTO `web_matter_attorney` VALUES ('62', '13', '1235', '5', 'Alaska', '0', '2015-02-07 13:35:23');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the function in this way `ma_datetime BETWEEN '2015-02-05' AND  '2015-02-07'` the time part will be set to `00:00:00` so the result of your query will be `ma_datetime BETWEEN '2015-02-05 00:00:00' AND  '2015-02-07 00:00:00'` so this value `2015-02-07 08:22:05` is outside of your range defined in BETWEEN.

Change to

```
`ma_datetime` BETWEEN '2015-02-05 00:00:00' AND  '2015-02-07 23:59:59'`
```

Comment: How can I set `00:00:00` and `23:59:59` in PHP as well. As query work dynamically. I mean in my dates `fromdate` and `todate`.

Comment: @Testing I can not see any php code in your question sorry. So i can not say it.

Comment: Here is my query: `$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM web_matter_attorney WHERE ma_datetime BETWEEN  '$date_from' AND '$date_to'") or die (mysqli_error());`

Comment: How about: `$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM web_matter_attorney WHERE ma_datetime BETWEEN '$date_from 00:00:00' AND '$date_to 23:59:59'") or die (mysqli_error());`

Comment: But you should use prepared statements.

Comment: how I can use prepared statements? Can you guide please?

Comment: read about it [http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Is this a right way to use: `'$date_from 00:00:00' AND '$date_to 23:59:59'` or it is a trick? I am newbie.

Comment: I think it is a possible way. But i am not a php progammer. I guess that your `$date_from` is a string, so this way is ok.

Comment: Fine. Thank You. But my `'$date_from' AND '$date_to'` are in `datetime` format in the database.

Comment: @Testing yes that is ok but in php that are strings?!

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query to get your required result.

```
SELECT * FROM `web_matter_attorney` WHERE DATE_FORMAT('ma_datetime','%Y-%m-d') >= DATE_FORMAT('2015-02-05','%Y-%m-d') AND DATE_FORMAT('ma_datetime','%Y-%m-d') <= DATE_FORMAT('2015-02-07','%Y-%m-d')
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: please try below query.

     SELECT * FROM `web_matter_attorney` WHERE date_format(ma_datetime,'%Y-%m-%d') IN ('2015-02-05', '2015-02-07')